# Excessive delete times on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, automated-builds

I made a professional case for upgrading the hard disk on my software development team's build server (Win7) with an SSD, on the grounds that it would speed the process up due to the large amount of files created by our nightly build process. I'm confident we won't suffer flash wear issues as we have a company policy that all machines are replaced in their entirety once over 24 months old.

The result was a 480Gb Kingston V300 being installed into the server.

Sure enough the build is now significantly faster, as expected; however the "clean" that takes place at the start of the process, which involves deleting about 2GB of files (~80k files and 2k folders) is now taking significantly longer; around 15-20min instead of the ~3min it took on the conventional hard disk, and undermining the benefit of the faster build times.

I've tried every means of "deleting" imaginable, within and outside of our build system's "clean", including just rmdir /s /q on the whole lot; and the result is the same.

Now things get interesting. In my large amounts of desperate experimentation, I've discovered that copying the entire directory that would get deleted to another location, and then deleting it, is extremely fast; around 45 seconds. Even just copying it in place ("Copy of  (1)" etc) and deleting the binary identical copy takes a very short time; but the original always still takes 15-20min no matter what I do with it.

So it seems that for some reason, "a bunch of stuff" on the drive takes immensely longer to delete once "another bunch of stuff" has been created on the drive; but is very quick to delete otherwise.

Can anyone explain what's going on, and possibly how I could mitigate this?

Comment: Not surwe how these old drives handles it, but copying would be a read (fast), write CONTINUOUS data (fast), delete a few blocks (fast).
While deleting random files could easily be "read 8k flash part, modify (mark delete) 512B in that, write new 8k part with theupdated data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Reconsider your workflow. Why not just rename the directory to get it out of the way, run your build on a new dir, then delete the old one in low usage hours. Even 3 minutes seems quite long to waste, if you can go with 0.1s.

Now concerning the delete times: I suspect, that for some reason something in that directory is still in use by the OS - maybe the classic (search indexer)? This could easily have been masked by the fact, that creation times were much longer on the rotating disk. You can verify that by trying to delete the stuff after a few hours and only then checking how long it takes.

**EDIT**

If the stuff is just 2GB in size, a RAM disk would be the obvious choice.